# Script didn't work on Firefox, 0 reaction on hover

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have a script that working perfectly on Chrome, but in Firefox there is no action after hovering linked object.

I tried to divide the script.js file for separate documents, but It won't help at all.

Here is the whole effect:

https://jsfiddle.net/lszewczyk45/9unawydo/9/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
const effect = new Effects('hover-effects');
effect.addEffect(document.querySelector('#cityEffect'), 'city', [ONMOUSEOVER]);
});
```

I think the problem is in calling the script - the lines at the end of the file, I pasted it above.

Comment: <?php

include "vendor/autoloader.php";

?> Are you asking about that?

Comment: You have to ask the developer of that library, it has nothing to do here with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what FireFox says about your Javascript code:

[image: This is what firefox says]

Answer (score 0):

I solve it, pasted in https://babeljs.io/, compile and change the js code.